# Beginner java constructor+loop+table ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, constructor, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

Beginner here, couldn't find the answer for my question. First, here's the code.

```
public class Worker{

    String name = "default";
    String surname = "default";
    int age = 0;

    public Worker(){ }

    public Worker(String inName, String inSurname, int inAge){
        name = inName;
        surname = inSurname;
        age = inAge;
    }

    public Worker(Worker worker){
        name = worker.name;
        surname = worker.surname;
        age = worker.age;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Company{   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int n = 2;
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[n];
        String[] names = {"John", "Kate"};
        String[] surnames = {"Doe", "McDonald"};
        int[] ages = {25, 31};

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){         
            workers[i] = new Worker(names[i], surnames[i], ages[i]);
        }       
            for(Worker p: workers){
            System.out.printf("%s, %s, %d \n",p.name,p.surname,p.age);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to create 3 'Worker' objects (let's assume that "n" value is being choosen by user) while only having two sets of data (names, surnames and ages). In case that "n" value is greater than names.length() I want new worker to be created with constructor "public Worker(){}".

How do I do that? I've tried several ideas but all of them give me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: It works fine, but if I changed "n" value to let's say "3" it would give me ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case that "n" value is greater than names.length I want new
>   worker to be created with constructor "public Worker(){}".

Something like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){         
    workers[i] = new Worker(names[i], surnames[i], ages[i]);
}
if (names.length < n) {
    for(int i = names.length; i<n; i++){
        workers[i] = new Worker();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes both loops can be written in much shorter code and yours is a good suggestion, but I think the way it is written now is easiest to understand for a beginner.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Except I had to change all instances of "names.length()" to "names.length"

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] names    = {"John", "Kate", "one_name_to_much"};
String[] surnames = {"Doe", "McDonald"};
int[]    ages     = {25, 31};

Worker[] workers  = new Worker[Math.max(Math.max(names.length, surnames.length), ages.length)];
```

That will check if names, surnames or ages has the most indices and then use this to initialize your `Worker` array.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the question..!! Why do you want to "change" the implementation style...??

Comment: @GokulNath please read the second last sentence of the question.